# Meteor Up and port 80

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I use [Meteor up](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up) for deploy my Meteor APP, but i would like change port off the docker image for use :80 with Nginx.

My mup.js :

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: 'XXX.XXX.XX.XX',
      username: 'xxxx',
      // pem:
      password: 'xxxx'
      // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  nodeVersion: '4.4.7',

  meteor: {
    name: 'app',
    path: '../app',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://xxxxx.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
    },

    dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    deployCheckWaitTime: 60
  },

  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

When i run `docker ps`, i see this :

```
fef11361e361g3e        abernix/meteord:base   "/bin/sh -c 'bash $ME"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp           app
```

Do you have any idea for change standars port ?

[image]

Thank you !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port on which your meteor app runs by adding `"port": XXXX` to the env section of the mup.js file.

```
env: {
  PORT: 3000
}
```

Comment: Hi. I've test and it failled on "Verifying Deployment". But i want change docker port, not meteor. I think i must check with Docker ?

Comment: So you want your nginx to listen on port 80, which will proxy pass to meteor running of some other port, say 3000? Basically, whatever port you run your meteor app in, that port will be forwarded to the system via docker automatically.

Comment: Yes, i would like use other port with meteor (why not 3000). But with PORT env i've verifyin deployment failled :(

Comment: Can you post the exact error during verify deployment?

Comment: From the screenshots you've attached, it doesn't look like theres any errors. In fact its going ahead and deploying Meteor on port 80

Comment: I run mup reconfig. You think i must run mup dploy ?

Comment: I think it work ! I've this line when i run docker ps : 0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp. The port 80 is free right ?

Comment: Hmm, i don't think port 80 is free. What this did was it ran the meteor app on port 3000, but mapped it to port 80 on the host. I think you may need to provide custom docker override commands to ensure free port 80 on the host.